# Issue with scroll in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, scroll

I have 1 problem with Visual Studio 2012 that I cannot scroll using the scroll bar. It shows like this:[image]

Is there any suggesstion to fix the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall VS 2012, and it can fix the issue.